# 'Textheight' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting an old VB6 project to .NET. In the VB6 Project `.TextHeight` and `.TextWidth` were used for a picture box object. After I migrated the project from VB6 to .NET the compiler threw the error `'Textheight' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'`

```
tmpX = tmpX - (p.TextWidth(tmpStr) / 2.0#)
```

and

```
tmpY = tmpY - (p.Textheight(tmpStr) / 2.0#)
```

What is the .NET equivalent for these?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with VB6 but I think that the title and the question itself has no sense, a picturebox control in VB.NET displays pictures, not text, it has not text properties. what object type if "p"?

Comment: @ElektroStudios pictureboxs could do this in VB6, and the title is the error message that studio gives me after the migration

Comment: Graphics.MeasureString

Comment: I'd look into `TextRenderer.MeasureText`.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet gets a high for some text headed for a multiline textbox or RTF box:

```
       txtPrompt.Height = Convert.ToInt32(Me.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(txtPrompt.Text, txtPrompt.Font, txtPrompt.Width).Height + 15)
```

.MeasureString() is the function you are looking for.